# Does the Micro-Miniaturized feat give me a free Mechanism pick with each gadget housing?

Tags: spycraft

The micro-miniaturized feat says that whenever I build or request a gadget, I may include one additional mechanism per gadget.  Does this mean I get an additional gadget pick, or that I may simply expend another gadget pick to put more mechanisms in a housing than what is usually possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Feat Doesn't Provide Free Stuff

The Benefit of the feat Micro-miniaturized (*Spycraft 2.0* 197) says

> When you build or request a gadget, each Mechanism is 1 size category smaller, and you *may* include 1 additional Mechanism per gadget.

No mention is made of how to include the additional Mechanism therefore standard rules apply. The feat Micro-miniaturized merely *allows* an additional Mechanism in a housing--it doesn't provide a *free* Mechanism. The additional Mechanism must still be built or requested,<sup>1</sup> its cost paid normally.

---

1. That is, gained when mission or personal gear can be selected, *not* only upon making a successful Request Check:

   > [The game] generally use[s] the term "request" to mean "acquire" through any means other than picking it up in game, so the feat [Mirco-miniaturized] covers possessions and mission gear as well.
   >
   > --[Patrick Kapera (04/15/08)](http://www.crafty-games.com/forum/index.php?topic=1465.0)

Comment: Please see this forum clarification on why Micro miniaturized applies to mission and personal gear: http://www.crafty-games.com/forum/index.php?topic=1465.0

Comment: @Mystagogue Fair enough. I like Pat a lot, but, man, that's a terrible design decision--[thesaurus](http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0012.html) FTW, dudes. Answer edited. Anyway, why not ask on the Crafty forums? The Crafty folk are good people, too.

Comment: I agree with your answer, and that's how I'd been playing it.  I didn't think there was any ambiguity.  But apparently my DM ruled that it was far more powerful in a previous game of his.  I mean, I'd love to take all my possessions as miniature gear and get a free mechanism with each, but come on.

Comment: @Mystagogue That's... pretty crazy, actually. I can see a new Control who doesn't fully understand the gear system's nuances making that call, or a Control wanting ultra-tech but infrequent gadgets (cyberpunk on a shoestring budget, maybe?), but the house-ruled feat'd be a no-brainer once everyone had some system mastery.